# define mylength function in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to figure out how to define a length function in racket.
Here's my code:

```
(define mylength
  (lambda (lst)
    (cond
     ((null? lst) 0)
     (else (+ 1 (mylength (cdr lst))))
     )))
```

If I try `(mylength '(1 2 3))` the result is 3. When I try `(mylength '(1 (2 3) 4))` the result still is 3. But the result should be 4. How do I do that? in Racket

Comment: Why should the result be `4`? There are only 3 elements in that list. One of the elements is another list, but it's just a single element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count nested elements separately, you need to recurse into `(car lst)` as well.

```
(define mylength
  (lambda (lst)
    (cond
     ((null? lst) 0)
     ((atom? lst) 1)
     (else (+ (mylength (car lst))
              (mylength (cdr lst))))
     )))
```

Note that this means that a nested empty list doesn't add to the length.

```
(mylength '(1 () 3))
```

will be `2`, not `3`.

Comment: Thank you very much